# Sign into social login on behalf of another device

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-signin, social-authentication

I have a kiosk like system that I would like users to authenticate with. It has social login with Gmail for example. It has no keyboard so signing in is a little awkward.

Is it possible to have another device, say a smartphone, sign in and transfer the credentials (tokens - not passwords ;) )? (presuming I have a way in linking the two - such as a QR code).

Sort of like how I can sign into Spotify on my echo from my phone.

Are credentials ever passed to device or is the server being granted access to my account and acting on behalf of the device?

I really want to know how this type of authentication scheme should be handled **correctly** in general.

Comment: So your "kiosk like system" has absolutely no means of input?

Comment: It has a camera (gesture based), and it is connected to the internet

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/devices

Answer (score 1):

Use https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/devices to generate a URL that user can visit on another device to approve the login (you could show a QR code for the link if you can display it). Remember to help people sign out when they are done if this is a public / shared system.

Comment: Great find, it's exactly what I'm looking for, only it's very google oriented... Are you aware of a more general solution that wouldn't prohibit using facebook, microsoft, etc? More so, can I expect to be able to do this without api support from the account provider?

Comment: Is it possible for the user to sign in on their smartphone linking with my service, then have my service grant access to the kiosk (again using e.g. QR codes)?

Comment: You'd have to check with Facebook / Microsoft for any support on their side. As for sign in to your service on a phone and then authenticate the kiosk, that'd be up to you to implement (how link the smartphone session to the kiosk session, which you could do yourself with a QR code that carries some session info)